# Webpack2 - How to inline an SVG file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, webpack-2

In `webpack.config.js` I am using the following `loader`:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [ 'file-loader' ]
}
```

Then in my `component`:

`import icon from '../img/icons/menu.svg'`

However, `console.log(icon) // 58f714c05099311f302aeb7d346be056.svg` shows that the value of `icon` is just a filename.

Is there a way to import the raw `svg`?

**Update:**

Using `url-loader` imports the `svg` as a base64 string.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

However, this also is not ideal since I am not able to style the `svg` with `CSS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.loaders =  ...
  {
      test: /\.(svg)$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader'
  }
```

This is because you are having the inline svg.
[Ref](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader/issues/6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use svg as background image with plugin https://github.com/kisenka/svg-fill-loader:

```
background-image: url('./styles/images/shark.svg?fill=$ddd');
background-size: cover;
width: 330px;
height: 250px;
```

With `background-size: cover;` svg will stretch across the container, so you can adjust size, and with `fill` you can change the color of the svg.